# How to build Stack widget with Positioned childrens without providing its static height to its parent?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a widget like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc4sr.jpg which is an item of listview.builder.

The widget tree is like this:

```
  return Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Divider(),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        width: screenWidth,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: 45,
              child: Row(
                children: [
// circular button widget
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
// text title widget

//text subtitle widget

// text duration widget

// progress duration widget

                        ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

//rotated day widget
            Positioned(
                left: 0,
                top: 10,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: -pi / 2,
                  child: Text('day'),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
```

The problem is that if I remove the height=100 of parent of stack, error occurs and nothing is rendered in the entire screen.This error is so bad that hot reload/restart does not work afterwards. I do not want to provide static height because the texts and other widgets in column are conditionally rendered and giving static height would sometimes leave massive space at bottom or not enough space to render widget in the stack.

I am using Stack here because the Transform.rotate widget would occupy same horizontal space as if it was not rotated and the space between rotated test and circular button would be large.

Comment: What does the error say? The errors are usually pretty helpful.

Comment: `var a = [10, 25, 15, 5];
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: a.length,
itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
return Column(
children: [
IntrinsicHeight(
child: Row(
children: [
SizedBox(
width: 64,
child: Transform.rotate(
angle: -math.pi / 2,
child: Center(child: Text('day $i')),
),
),
Expanded(child: Text('foo$i ' * a[i], textScaleFactor: 2)),
],
),
),
Divider(),
],
);
}
);`

Comment: here is the error log after removing height from parent of stack: https://filebin.net/snee7cl8zzwgtkuf

I will try IntrinsicHeight mentionned by @pskink and let you guys know.

Comment: @pskink using your solution fixes the error but the content of stack widget is not rendered at all. http://imgur.com/gallery/oKOR7Sb .

Comment: @pskink I used IntrinsicHeight widget in my code without removing Stack. I missed that you wrapped Transform with SizedBox. Let me test that out.

Comment: @pskink I used your widget, error from stack is resolved but transformed widget still occupies the same horizontal space. https://imgur.com/gallery/ymkKNXx 
I wrapped sized box with container and provided color to see its layout.

Comment: if 64 is too wide in `SizedBox( width: 64, ` use `32` or `48` (whatever you want)

Comment: If I do that text does not fit in the box and it becomes multiline.